# if TXT empty echo message possible?

Tags: php

Hi I have a piece of code that is able to delete each newline in a txt file. Now my question is if the txt file is empty it gives an error message that `$line` doesn't exist. Now i want to add a piece off code that if txt has no content it echo's a message like "no emails in the list"

```
<?php
$delete = @$_GET['delete'];
$textFile = file("../emaillist/emaillist.txt");
$lines = count($textFile);

if($delete != "" && $delete >! $lines || $delete === '0') {
    $textFile[$delete] = "";
    $fileUpdate = fopen("../emaillist/emaillist.txt", "wb");
    for($a=0; $a<$lines; $a++) {
           fwrite($fileUpdate, $textFile[$a]);
    }
    fclose($fileUpdate);

   echo"<p class='accept'>Contact verwijderd!</p>";

   exit;
}

foreach($textFile as $key => $val) {
$pre= "<label style='float:left;' class='tablog3a'>";
$line = @$line . $pre . $val . "</label><a style='float:right;' href =?delete=$key><img class='clickreverse' src='images/deletetodo.png'></a><br>";
}
echo $line;
?>
```

I allready tried:

```
else {
echo "no emails in the list";
}
```

but that gave nothing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few ways to check if a file is empty:

```
$textfile = file('text.txt');
$lines = count($textfile);

if (empty($lines)) 
    echo 'file is empty';
```

Or:

```
if (filesize('text.txt') === 0) 
    echo 'file is empty';
```

Or, if you want to check if it is empty, not including blank lines or extra whitespace:

```
$textfile = trim(file_get_contents('text.txt'));
if (empty($textfile))
    echo 'file is empty';
```